# Arduino Compiling errors with Wifi Nat code for a Wifi Extender

Tags: wifi, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm using this git repo by martin-ger
https://github.com/martin-ger/lwip_nat_arduino
I tried compiling for the same code but I'm getting a lot of errors 
Can someone help ?

error: field 'start_ip' has incomplete type
  struct ip_addr start_ip;

error: field 'end_ip' has incomplete type
  struct ip_addr end_ip;

error: field 'ip' has incomplete type
  struct ip_addr ip;

error: could not convert 'myIP' from 'IPAddress' to 'ip_addr_t {aka ip_addr}'
                                                              ^
error: 'IP_NAPT_MAX' was not declared in this scope

error: 'IP_PORTMAP_MAX' was not declared in this scope

Comment: what version of the esp8266 core for Arduino do you use? did you read that the 'library' is obsolete?

Comment: NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12)
I didn't understand what you meant when you mentioned library

Comment: at the link in Question: "** This lib is somewhat obsolete because...".  current versions of esp8266 core are 2.4.x or 2.5.x